# From the Appium server I am trying to get the launch latency time of an application using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium

I am trying to find the launch latency of an settings app directly from the `appium` server.

Can you please help in letting me know what will be the code to capture the details in python please.

Below is my code:-

---

```
from appium import webdriver

desired_cap = {
    "platformName": "Android",
    "platformVersion": "10.0",
    "deviceName": "1000686d",
    "automationName": "Appium",
    "appPackage": "com.android.settings",
    "appActivity": "com.android.settings.Settings",
    "newCommandTimeout": "600",
    "autoLaunch": "false", #this will not launch the app by itself so that we can measure the launch latency in a controlled way.
    "eventTimings": "true"
}

driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub",desired_cap)

print ("Launching Settings")
driver.start_activity("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings");

server_events = driver.getEvents()
```

---

Output:-

```
Launching Settings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vinay/Desktop/Python/V2/Session_2/Launch_Latency.py", line 21, in <module>
    server_events = driver.getEvents()
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'getEvents'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

---

Comment: `driver.getEvents()` this is a java method not Python

Comment: Thanks Narendra. Basically I was looking for a way to read elements from the Appium server with python. Can you please help me with that ?